# How to pass a class name with a string in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, eval

I want to get all of objects that are related to an instance of models. 
Because my code is kinda generic, I pass the related table as an string and use `eval()` function to convert it to the related table class. But I got an error. 
Suppose that we have an instance of a table like `self.casefile`; this is a part of my code:

```
 def related_models_migration(self):
        opts = self.casefile._meta
        table_name = 'Files'
        for f in opts.many_to_many:
            name = ''.join(f.name.split('_'))
            table_name += name.capitalize()
            objects = self.casefile.eval(table_name).all()
```

and I got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-025484eeba97> in <module>
----> 1 obj.related_models_migration()

~/Documents/kangaroo/etl/data_migration.py in related_models_migration(self)
     28             name = ''.join(f.name.split('_'))
     29             table_name += name.capitalize()
---> 30             objects = self.casefile.eval(table_name).all()
     31 
     32             for d in dir(etl.models):

AttributeError: 'FilesCasefiles' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

How can I pass the class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `eval(..)` for that. What you probably want to use here is `getattr(..)`:

```
def related_models_migration(self):
    opts = self.casefile._meta
    table_name = 'Files'
    for f in opts.many_to_many:
        name = ''.join(f.name.split('_'))
        table_name += name.capitalize()
        objects = getattr(self.casefile, table_name).all()
```

I am not sure you should use `table_name += …` here however, since it will each time add *more* content to the `table_name`. You likely want to use something like `table_name = 'Files{}'.format(name.capitalize())`.

> **Note**: normally related fields are *not* capitalized. One writes `users` or `user_set`, not <s>`Users`</s>.

Comment: Yes, I have to take `table_name` into the for condition.

Answer (score 1):

Django provides [a way to do this,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#application-configuration) although you do need to specify the name of the app in which the moodel is defined (because it's possible to have two models with the same name in different apps).

> apps.get_model(app_label, model_name, require_ready=True)¶
>
> Returns the Model with the given app_label and model_name. 
>   As a shortcut, this method also accepts a single argument in the form
>   app_label.model_name. model_name is case-insensitive.